# Curl -s command within applescript stopped today

Tags: curl, web-scraping, applescript

For years I have used:

```
set incomingtext to do shell script "curl -s  " & quoted form of (urltext)
```

To be honest I have a monkey see monkey do approach to this. The `(urltext)` was generated within AppleScript and then the incoming text then parsed to obtain the desired values. This morning it failed.

This AppleScript explains the problem:

```
set urltext to "https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/RDSB.L?p=RDSB.L"
set incomingtext to do shell script "curl -s  " & quoted form of (urltext)
set x to count the characters of incomingtext
```

result:

> ```
> error "The command exited with a non-zero status." number 35
> ```

Applescript Version 2.3 (118) Snow leopard any help appreciated. Thanks Roger

Comment: a 'non-zero status' implies that the shell command failed, not the AppleScript. Clicking that link, I see that Yahoo has put up a blocking overlay asking you to accept changes to their privacy policy. That's probably what's causing `curl` to fail. If you clear that manually by accepting or rejecting, I suspect your script will go back to working as it always did.

Comment: Thanks Ted, using chrome the page displays fine. changing the suffix from -s to -v gives"About to connect() to uk.finance.yahoo.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 87.248.114.12... connected
* Connected to uk.finance.yahoo.com (87.248.114.12) port 443 (#0)
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [data not shown]
* error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
* Closing connection #0

curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure". I have found that curl was updated yesterday.Does it use a curl server to query

Comment: "handshake failure": see [How to fix curl sslv3 alert handshake failure?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192944/how-to-fix-curl-sslv3-alert-handshake-failure)